# Issue - infinite loop using while on ksh script

Tags: shell-script, scripting, ksh

I'm writting a scsript to automate some check at work & i have trouble on only 1 standing issue which is the script never ending.

It do the all task over & over.
There are 2 while loop & once finishe the first one it logicaly start the 2nd one.
Once 2nd one it's done it start back on the first 1.

Also i would like to make it end once the both loop are finished 1 after the other.
I'm not doing script very often and the answer could possibly be easy but i cannot find one that suit my script so far.

Thank you for your help.

Below the script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
#
#
#
#
day=`date +%Y%m%d`
BASEDIR=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))
cd $BASEDIR

cd /export/home/prodwww/ftp_backup/conf
grep "mds_lin_m" *|cut -d " " -f1 > /export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/tmp/mono_list_"$day".log

cat /export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/tmp/mono_list_"$day".log |cut -d "    " -f1 > /export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/log/mono_list_"$day"_.log
sed -i -e "s/:/\//g" /export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/log/mono_list_"$day"_.log

cat /export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/log/mono_list_'date'_.log |while read lines
do
grep -HL 'NbChannel' /export/home/prodwww/ftp_backup/data/"$lines"/mds.ini >>  /export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/log/result_"$day"_.log;
done

cat  /export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/log/result_"$day"_.log|cut -d"/" -f 7-8>  /export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/log/autoswitch-list.log
sed -i -e "s/\// @ /g" /export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/log/autoswitch-list.log

awk -F" " '{print $3 $2 $1}' /export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/log/autoswitch-list.log > /export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/log/check-list.log
        cat  /export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/log/check-list.log |while read target
do
echo "$target">/export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/log/account.txt

cat /export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/log/account.txt|cut -d"@" -f1>/export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/log/login.txt
logon=$(cat /export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/log/login.txt)
echo $target>>/export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/data/autoswitch_check_"$day".log ;  /usr/local/bin/rww CMD "$target" "ls -lrt /export/home/"$logon"/mds/conf/autoswitch.ini">> /export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/data/autoswitch_check_"$day".log

done
exit
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) give us a _minimal_ version of your script that reproduces the problem. Start removing commands from your script until you find the minimal set that still shows the same behavior. ii) tell us _exactly_ how you run the script, it doesn't make sense that it would move back to a previous loop, so it might be that you are launching it wrong somehow. iii) ideally, also provide a simple data set we can use to reproduce the issue. There's nothing super obviously wrong apart from some bad coding practices, so you need to do some debugging first.

Answer (score 1):

There is no obvious reason for any loop to become "infinite". However, re-writing the exact same script but extracting each file name to a variable we get a more legible version, IMO.

```
day=`date +%Y%m%d`
BASEDIR=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))
cd $BASEDIR


dir1="/export/home/prodwww/ftp_backup/conf"
log1="/export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/tmp/mono_list_$day.log"
log2="/export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/log/mono_list_$day_.log"
log3="/export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/log/mono_list_date_.log"
ini1="/export/home/prodwww/ftp_backup/data/$lines/mds.ini"
log4="/export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/log/result_$day_.log"
log5="/export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/log/autoswitch-list.log"
log6="/export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/log/check-list.log"
txt1="/export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/log/account.txt"
txt2="/export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/log/login.txt"
log7="/export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/data/autoswitch_check_$day.log" 
ini2="/export/home/$logon/mds/conf/autoswitch.ini"
log8="/export/home/prodwww/Production/Check/data/autoswitch_check_$day.log"



cd "$dir1"
grep "mds_lin_m" * | cut -d " " -f1 >"$log1"

cat "$log1" | cut -d "    " -f1 >"$log2"
sed -i -e "s/:/\//g" "$log2"

cat "$log3"| while read lines
do
    grep -HL 'NbChannel' "$ini1" >> "$log4"
done

cat  "$log4" | cut -d"/" -f 7-8 > "$log5"
sed -i -e "s/\// @ /g" "$log5"

awk -F" " '{print $3 $2 $1}'  "$log5"> "$log6"
cat  "$log6" | while read target
do
    echo "$target" > "$txt1"

    cat "$txt1" | cut -d"@" -f1 > "$txt2" 
    logon=$( cat "$txt2" )
    echo $target >> "$log7";
    /usr/local/bin/rww CMD "$target" "ls -lrt $ini2" >> "$log7" 

done
exit
```

And then, it seems obvious that repeating the exact same command `grep -HL 'NbChannel' "$ini1" >> "$log4"` for each line in `log3` will put a lot of repeating lines in `log4`.

Maybe that is not what you want. And that is the reason that all the following command are repeated over and over again on the same values from `log4`.

Note that `log2` should always be empty as `log1` is cut on the first space. Then `log1` will have no spaces. It is not possible for `cut -d "    " -f1` to match anything.